# Create Chromium diff aka patch installer

Tags: installation, diff, patch, chromium

I am working on Chromium fork and I have managed to create some diff patches for exe and dll files by using Courgette but whenever I run this command: ninja -C out\Default mini_installer it just creates a full installer. I tried this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-discuss/O9uuZGYcWNY/xV85Lg7T-FAJ but it still creates a full installer. If anyone can give me a pointer on how to create a diff installer like Google do when patching Chrome on Windows then it would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Asesh has explained how he achieve it over [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/McS0jwJFPYQ/e6J2qcTYEQAJ). Thanks Asesh for detail explanation.